Can the compact convex set in real space be represented as an intersection of some bounded functions?
I know that by Krein–Milman theorem, a compact convex set is the convex hull of its extreme points. My question is: when there are infinite extreme points in the compact convex set, e.g., the set is a circle or some angles are like a part of a circle, can we always represent this set by intersections of some supporting hyperplanes? If we can do this, how many supporting hyperplanes in this case? (I guess the number is infinite)
The set we considered here is in any finite dimension space.

I'm not sure what you mean by "intersection of some bounded function" but you can always write a compact convex set $K$ as an intersection of half spaces, although you may indeed need an infinite number of them. At each point of the boundary, there is (at least) one tangent hyperplane or as you said "supporting" hyperplane, and by convexity, your set lies entirely on one side of it. Thus $K$ is the intersection of all these half spaces.
Since you talk about functions and support hyperplane, it sounds like the object your are looking for is the support function. If you have a convex body $K$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ then its support function is the function $h_K: S^{n-1}\to \mathbb{R}$ given for all $u\in S^{n-1}$ by
\begin{equation} h_K(u):=\sup_{x\in K}\langle u, x\rangle.\end{equation}
I like to think of it as the function that takes a direction $u$ and gives you the supporting hyperplane of $K$ in that direction. Then you can reconstruct $K$ from $h_K$ as explained above. So to formally answer your question, you need at most as many half spaces as there are points on the sphere.
Lots of other properties of $K$ can also be read from from the support function and it is a very powerful tool. I suggest you take a look at the standard reference for this subject which is "Convex Bodies: The Brunn Minkowski Theory" by Rolf Schneider.
